# C++ Operator Overload [ ]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

let's say i have the following classes:

```
class temp1 {
private:
    int A;
    double B;
};

class temp2 {
private:
    int A[20];
    double B;
};

void main() {
    temp1 a[100];
    temp2 b;
}
```

now the question is why do i need to overload the operator [ ] only for temp2 and not for temp 1 aswell ?
i know that inorder to get to the 10 index in veriable A in class temp 2 i will need to overload indeed the operator [ ] but in the main i have array of classes
(temp1 a[100]) so how the compiler knows what will i mean when i will use [ ] operator without overloading one.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code? Are you getting errors?

Comment: "*i know that inorder to get to the 10 index in veriable A in class temp 2 i will need to overload indeed the operator [ ]*". Why?

Comment: how is it related to errors ? i wont get any errors.. but that isnt my question
if i will try to do b[5] i will get error even though i was aiming to get the [i] index of A from temp 2 but the complier doesnt understand this without the operator overloading.
im asking some thing else, why doesnt temp1 need operator overload ?
(i dont care if it works or not im trying to understand here some thing)

Comment: @Amadeus its private i cant do any thing like that....

Comment: @GauravSehgal because lets say i write in main
b[5]
the compiler cant translate it without me overloading the [ ] operator
i will need to overload the [ ] and return A at index 5.

Comment: I have not see that. You question has no sense too, because they are diferents things. `a` is an array of `temp1` while `b` is a object of `temp2` that has a member of an array of 20 `int`s

Comment: @Itay.V So you want a functionality to be able to do `b[5]` and get `temp2::A[5]`.This is completely different from `a[5]`.You need an extra functionality for `temp2`.That is why you need overloading.

Comment: `how the compiler knows what will i mean when i will use [ ] operator without overloading one.` It doesn't. Like you said `temp1 a[100]` creates an array of 100 `temp1` instances.

Comment: @GauravSehgal i know why i need overload for temp2 im asking why dont i need overload for temp1
i have an array of temp1 class how the compiler does understand when i'll write some thing like a[30] in main ?

Comment: @Itay.V `a[30]` would return the `temp1` object with index `30` from the array `a`.  This is completely different than something like `b.A[10]`, where you are taking the `int` with index `10` from the array `A` inside the `temp2` named `b`.  If you wanted `b[10]` to work, that's when you would need to add `operator[]` for `temp2`

Comment: as @Amadeus and @0x5453 said.`a` and `b` are completely different things.You need to understand this first.

Comment: Oh god... For the 10th time I do know the difference between them I'm asking why don't I need to overload for the first example ?

Comment: suppose I have this definition: `int A[10];` Now, how compiler knows how to access `A[5]`? Because it was designed to achieve that. Change `int` for `temp1` and you have you answer. Because this how the language and compiler works

Comment: @Itay.V I'm not sure that you do know the difference... `a` is an *array* of 100 instances of `temp1`s.  `b` is a *single instance* of a `temp2`.  A single object is not the same as an array of objects; arrays can use the bracket operator because that is how arrays are defined in the language.  If you want to use an *object* with the bracket operator, you have to define the behavior yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, local variable `a` is an *array*. A value with type array of `T` does not behave like a value with type `T`, it behaves more similarly to a pointer of type `T*`.

---

Pointers (nor arrays) can't be used directly as though they were the type that they point to.

Consider this `Foo` type:

```
class Foo {
    public: doStuff() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If I have

```
Foo* f = new Foo[2];
```

I cannot say `f.doStuff()`; doing that would require `f` be a `Foo` (rather than a `Foo*`).

In order to get a `Foo` from `f`, I have to *dereference* it as `*f`. For example

```
(*f).doStuff(); // -> hello
```

This clearly shows that C++ treats pointer types as special -- they automatically have special operations defined, one of which is `*`.

I defined `f` to be a (dynamically allocated) array of two elements.

We can refer to the first element by `*f`, *or* using `f[0]`.

The second element can be referred to by `*(f+1)` *or* by `f[1]`.

`[]` is another special operator of pointer (and array) types in C++. The meaning is more or less

```
T& operator[](T* pointer, int index) {
    return *(pointer + index);
}
```

---

In your example, local variable `b` is of type `temp2`. `temp2` isn't a pointer, so the compiler doesn't have any definition for `b[10]`. If you wanted to do that, the type `temp2` would have to explicitly provide the definition for that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly,in the following case, compiler will assume that you are specifying the length of the array that you are declaring:

`int A[20];`

and in the following case, it will assume that you're using subscript operator "[]" to reach to the specified index in brackets:

`A[2] = 3; // after variable declaration.`

Comment: not exactly, im just wondering if i'll continue working on my main and do some thing like A[15] why wouldnt i need to overload the operator, why does the compiler understand that i meant that im looking for 15th index in A array

Comment: @Lianthe: Actually it's because the `[]` is the indexing operator on a C-style array, not on the type itself. It would work for a C-style array of any type, not just primitives.

Comment: @AndyG You are right, i was thinking completely something else :o

Comment: @Itay.V like AndyG said, you don't need to overload `[]` operator for C-style arrays. But the case you will want to to overload indexing operator is when you create a class like vector<T>.